# Change hardware name

Tags: rooting, settings

I'm using official Android Emulator. When I run this I get:

```
adb shell getprop | grep hardware
```

I get

```
[ro.boot.hardware]: [goldfish]
[ro.hardware]: [goldfish]
[ro.kernel.androidboot.hardware]: [goldfish]
```

I want to rename **goldfish** to any other word.

I can run emulator in debug mode `emulator -avd test -show-kernel -verbose` to see kernel parameters:

```
  kernel.path = /home/artyom/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = yes
```

So, Android Emulator passes `androidboot.hardware=goldfish` to the QEMU.

Lets dive into Android source.

http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/system/core/init/util.c#407

Here we can see, that passing hardware via kernel command line makes it unchangable.

```
void get_hardware_name(char *hardware, unsigned int *revision)
{
    const char *cpuinfo = "/proc/cpuinfo";
    char *data = NULL;
    size_t len = 0, limit = 1024;
    int fd, n;
    char *x, *hw, *rev;

    /* Hardware string was provided on kernel command line */
    if (hardware[0])
        return;
```

According to [this](http://elinux.org/Android_Booting), hardware name used to init file **init.machine_name.rc**, so renaming goldfish to any other name must be combined with renaming **init.goldfish.rc** to **init.anyname.rc**.

So my question is, how can I force different hardware name ? How I can different **androidboot.hardware** value to the qemu ? What files, other than **init.goldfish.rc** should I change ? Different hardware name must be forced while compiling ?

I've tried adding this to **.config** file:

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE="androidboot.hardware=randomname android.checkjni=1"
CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTRA=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE=y
```

It didn't help.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572781/android-boot-where-is-the-init-hardware-rc-read-in-init-c-where-are-servic

Additional info: https://wiki.diebin.at/Under_the_hood_of_Android_Emulator_(appcert)#Initialize_Goldfish_hardware

Comment: 3 years later but.. did you manage to do it?